# file validation, preserving the file location

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, preserve

I'm trying to create a full validation page for an input (sql insert) form.

What I've typically been doing are the following to preserve the values already input on the page in case one piece of validation fails (in which case the user is returned to the form to correct it with an error shown).

```
 echo 'value=" ';
 if(isset($_POST['NewGameName'])){ 
     echo $_POST['NewGameName']; 
 } // for text-fields
 echo '<option value="'.$i.'" ';

 if(isset($_POST['Score'])){ 
     if($i == $_POST['Score']){
         echo'selected="selected"';
     }
 }

 echo '>'.$i.'</option>'; // for dropdowns
```

But I can't seem to find a way to preserve the file location if the page is refreshed. Is there a way to do this? I've read that it's always cleared for security reasons which would be annoying but if it's the standard I guess people are used to it.

Comment: Store the correct files in a temporary holding area and display the details about them on the form. i.e the user only has to re-enter the ones that failed.

Comment: So if i'm using this as the file location  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['BackgroundUpload']['tmp_name'], 'Pictures/'.mysqli_escape_string($dbc, trim($Title)).'/BackgroundTMP.'.$backgroundEXT['extension']); how would i apply it to the input to preserve the location if this has been set?

Comment: You don't have to preserve and show the input location again as the files are already on the server. You just ask them for the files that failed.

Comment: Yes but i don't want to delete things from the input when something fails so that only the failed elements are left displaying, therefore, i'll need to either leave the file to be overwritten by a second upload which will be required upon failure, or, point the file to the folder where the image was uploaded to successfully first time. I'm asking how i'd do the latter.

Comment: Just display the details of the valid files on the form so that the user knows what they were. i.e. replace the 'file input' field with the details of the uploaded file. Provide a 'delete' button / checkbox for the file if they want to change the file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a hidden field to store the file name and change the name through javascript by using onchange event on the actual file field. 
as soon as file name changes you could update the hidden field value.
you get the hidden field value in the post variable and use this variable to refresh the value of the file field

Comment: it's not just the file name i'd want though, it's the location. 

so i don't just want image.png, i want
user/documents/pictures/images/image.png so the user doesn't have to find the image again (although i know it's just a matter of clicking the link and selecting the correct image, as the chose file button should remember the location the image was at, somehow). It would just reduce errors if the image didn't need to be selected again every time there was an unrelated error elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options.

1. is to use Ajax for validation. This way you don't leave the form with the filepath.
2. Use javascript after the validation to go back in history `history.go(-1)` to the previous screen. I think when using history, the form entries are preserved.